# It's geocaching month

Tags: discussion, topics

It's the month of GeoCaching. There is currently a challenge running, to find a cache each day in August, so it's a good occasion to ask questions in [geocaching](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geocaching) tag.

Maybe the cachers are too tired after looking for caches each day after work to post some questions here?

There was once a concept of featured topics, but unfortunately, it seems to be dead...